# Al Hamichya and Al Haetz

Tags: food, fruits, blessing

If I eat a pastry and grapes at one sitting, do i make two brachos achronot al hamichya and an al haetz? or may I combine the words into one bracha acharona by saying "al haetz V'al hamichya" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latter is correct. Assuming you ate a proper shiur of both the pastry and the grapes (which creates a requirement for a bracha achrona), you would combine the bracha achrona.

**However**, the correct order would be "al hamichya v'al hakalkalah, v'al haetz v'al pri haetz" (על המחיה ועל הכלכלה, ועל העץ ועל פרי העץ)

In general, the correct order is:

1. Al Hamichya
2. Al Hagafen
3. Al Haetz

Similarly, at the end you would substitute the for all the food-types you ate...

Source: Siddur Tefillas Shlomo (Artscroll), and Sefer Sharei Haberacha (page 311)

Comment: And if you had lots of grapes but only a nibble of cookie, once you're making an "al ha'etz", you can add in the phrase "al hamichya." (Igros Moshe.)

Comment: @Shalom I assume "could" but don't have to. Is there any advantage to doing so?